# Snowflake - Select unique rows based on primary key from staging area

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In the case I have staged area created from a csv file that has two rows with the same primary key value 5 and another row with value 6. Is there a way that I can run a select query (used for a copy into later) that can get the last row with primary key 5 and the row with 6? Collectively only returning the two unique primary key rows (preferably the last one).

After I've "put" my file into the staging area, I understand to get my columns and values I'd run the following:
`select t.$1, t.$2, t.$3, t.$4 from @MY_STAGE( FILE_FORMAT => 'csv') t` and the would get all 3 rows and their respective columns and values in order. Is there a way that I can improve the query to return two rows, one of with primary key 5 and one for key 6?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:

```
select Distinct * from @MY_STAGE( FILE_FORMAT => 'csv') t
```

Or a `row_number()` over `( Partition By Primary_key Order By < a suitable column > ) = 1`.

Are the 2 rows with same primary key exactly the same or do some values differ (like if primary key is 5, do some other columns have different values)?

Comment: Hi thank you for a quick response, at least one or many of the other column values will have a different value but the same primary key. So ideally, grabbing the last one would be the most updated values between the matching primary key rows.

Comment: okay then i would suggest you go with this approach: row_number() over ( Partition By Primary_key Order By < a suitable column > ) = 1

if you have something like a time stamp or any numerical value then use it in order by clause with "desc" that should give you the latest row with rownumber as 1

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.